# List and Integer Python

Tags: python, list, swap

I am trying to write a code that changes the position of an integer inside a list (basically swaps the position with another integer)

I have tried to use all logic, but still can't understand why my code is messing up:

```
SpecialNum = 10
def number_move(move_number):
    for elements in range(len(move_number)):

    if ( SpecialNum != move_number[-1]):


        x = move_number.index(SpecialNum)
        y = move_number.index(SpecialNum)+1
        move_number[y], move_number[x] = move_number[x], move_number[y]



return (move_number)
```

the output should be:

```
[1,2,3,10,4,5,6]
>>>[1,2,3,4,10,5,6]
```

but output comes as:

> > > [1,2,3,4,5,6,10]

Comment: Whenever I try to use all logic, it takes infinite time.

Comment: @abarnert .. lol that is true...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your actual indentation looks like this:

```
SpecialNum = 10
def number_move(move_number):
    for elements in range(len(move_number)):
        if ( SpecialNum != move_number[-1]):
            x = move_number.index(SpecialNum)
            y = move_number.index(SpecialNum)+1
            move_number[y], move_number[x] = move_number[x], move_number[y]
    return move_number
```

… the problem is that you're swapping the `10` to the right over and over in a loop, until it reaches the very end.

If that isn't what you want, why do you have the `for elements in range(len(move_number))` in the first place? Just take it out, and it will only get swapped right once.

---

As a side note, you rarely need `range(len(eggs))`; you can just do `for egg in eggs` (or, if you need the index along with the actual object, `for index, egg in enumerate(eggs)`).

Also, you've got a whole lot of extra parentheses that aren't needed, and make the code harder to read.

Meanwhile, every call to `index` has to search the entire list to find your object's position; if you already *know* the position, it's better to just use it. Not only is it a lot faster, and simpler, it's also more robust—if there are two elements of the list with the same value, `index` can only find the first one. In your case, there's no obvious way around using `index`, but at least you can avoid calling it twice.

Putting that together:

```
SpecialNum = 10
def number_move(move_number):
    x = move_number.index(SpecialNum)
    y = x + 1
    if y != len(move_number):
        move_number[y], move_number[x] = move_number[x], move_number[y]
```

Finally, I said there's no *obvious* way around using `index`… but is there a non-obvious way? Sure. If you're going to call `index` repeatedly on the same object, we can make the last-found index part of the interface to the function, or we can even store a cache inside the function. The simplest way to do this is to turn the whole thing into a generator. A generator that mutates its arguments can be kind of confusing, so let's make it return copies instead. And finally, to make it customizable, let's take a parameter so you can specify a different SpecialNum than 10.

```
SpecialNum = 10
def number_move(move_number, special_num=SpecialNum):
    for x, element in reversed(list(enumerate(move_number))):
        if element == special_num:
            while x+1 < len(move_number):
                move_number = (move_number[:x] + 
                               [move_number[x+1], move_number[x]] +
                               move_number[x+2:])
                yield move_number
                x += 1
```

Now, it'll move *all* of the 10s to the end, one step at a time. Like this:

```
>>> n = [1, 10, 2, 3, 10, 4, 5, 6]
>>> for x in number_move(n):
...     print(x)
[1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 10, 5, 6]
[1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 6]
[1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10]
[1, 2, 10, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 10, 4, 5, 6, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 5, 6, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 6, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 10]
```

Comment: I wanted the program to scan the list and find the position of the SpecialNumber ...

But now I see ur logic ... the .index method actually does that !!

Comment: @user2954367: Exactly! I probably should have explained that better, but I'm glad you got it anyway.

Comment: guess I want using all the logic  :p

Comment: @user2954367: To deny your request would be highly illogical. :)

Comment: @JonClements: You can get rid of more than that. I touched on that in my last paragraph, but I should probably be more explicit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `for` loop :)

```
def number_move(move_number):
    x = move_number.index(SpecialNum)
    y = move_number.index(SpecialNum)+1
    move_number[y], move_number[x] = move_number[x], move_number[y]
```

Alternative:

```
>>> def number_move(m, i):
        num = m.pop(i)
        m.insert(i+1, num)
        return m
>>> l = number_move([1,2,3,10,4,5,6], 3)
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Popping it out and inserting it back in isn't any simpler than just swapping it with its neighbor.

Comment: Yep, just wanted to try it myself. Updated with a fix to his method.